# What is the outcome of decreasing a char pointer?

Tags: c, shell, pointers, unix

So I was studying a code about a custom linux shell and I am having a hard time understanding this section:

```
// add null to the end
char *end;
end = tokenized + strlen(tokenized) - 1;
end--;
*(end + 1) = '\0';
```

I don't understand what decreasing a char pointer yields and how this section functions in general, I get that it is pointing end at the last position of the tokenized array but I don't understand the following two lines. If anything similar has been posted I don't mind supplying me the links (although I did a good amount of research). Thank you!

Also a quick question is: I don't believe end is an array. Am I wrong on this?

Answer (score 1):

Decreasing the pointer moves its location in memory to the preceding address. In the case of a `char *` string, `end` will now point to its preceding character.

```
// add null to the end
// declare a `char *`
char *end;
// set `end` to point to the last character of `tokenized`
end = tokenized + strlen(tokenized) - 1; 
// decrease `end`; now points to the character before the character is was pointing to
end--;
// set the character after the one `end` points to to `NUL`
*(end + 1) = '\0';
```

I commented your code as I understand it...

Comment: Thank you for the clarification but is there any  point in pointing it to the preceding character and then doing this: *(end + 1) = '\0' ? And won't it override the last character of the string with \0?

Comment: Doesn't seem to make sense? Assume your string is `"string"`. After `tokenized + strlen(tokenized) + 1`, `end` points to the last `g` in `"string"`. Decreasing the pointer now makes it point to `n`, which will then be replaced by `NUL` (`\0`)

Comment: Also, `strlen()` only works on NUL terminated strings. Finally: What you have will shorten the string by 2 characters.

Comment: But shouldn't null be after the g of string?

Comment: After `end = tokenized + strlen(tokenized) - 1`, `end` points at the `"`. The next two statements are equivalent to `*end-- = 0;` or `end[0] = 0; --end;` or `--end;   end[1] = 0;`: the `"` is overwritten with `0` and `end` points at the `g`.

Comment: @nielsbot: are you sure? can you see the tokenizer? do you know what the input is? Certainly, shells should be able to handle quoted strings, so it's not at all unreasonable to guess that this code comes from the part which is trying to do that. But it's true, it's just a guess. From the way you wrote your comment, I thought we had the same guess. Evidently I was wrong.

Answer (score 0):

```
char *end;
end = tokenized + strlen(tokenized) - 1; // 
end--;
*(end + 1) = '\0';
```

> strlen(tokenized)

This is the offset location of the null-terminator in the `tokenized` string.
Meaning, if you increment the pointer by this offset (the amount of non-null characters) you end up with a pointer to the index right after the last character. In order to get the index right on the last character you substract one from the offset.

Let `offset = strlen(tokenized) - 1`

> tokenized + offset

This means the pointer `tokenized` is moved by an *offset*. If the pointer would reference 1 byte that means it just increments by 1, if its 2 bytes by 2, and so on. This is because if you have, e.g. an array of ints you want to access only integers when taking offsets of that array pointer. The int is at least 2 bytes in size so the pointer will move at least 2 bytes further when being incremented.

> end--

Same thing as above, this *decrements* the pointer by one, since we moved to the last character of the string using our offset we are now at the second to last character in the string, not much to say other than this is equivalent to `end = end - 1;`.

> *(end + 1) = '\0'

Again, we move an offset of `1` ahead with the pointer, so we once again point at the last character of the string. This is rather redundant since we only just decremented the pointer by the same offset. The only difference here is that the pointer `end` itself is not changed.

Then we *dereference* the pointer and write to it, this means we change the value the pointer is currently pointing at, namely the last character of the string. We change this to `'\0'` because that means we move the terminating null-byte to this location, effectively shortening the string by cutting of the last character.

The code here is equivalent to

```
size_t len = strlen(tokenized);
tokenized[len - 1] = '\0';
char *end = tokenized + len - 2; // we still have this pointer
```

Note that we do `-2` now because we include the `end--;` statement.
The current `end` remains pointing at the last character of the now shortened string.

An illustration of what is happening:

1. `tokenized = "hello world"; // [h e l l o  w o r l d \0 ]`
2. `tokenized = "hello worl";  // [h e l l o  w o r l \0 \0 ]`

> I don't believe end is an array. Am I wrong on this?

Arrays are *essentially* just pointers to memory locations. There are a few differences like `sizeof` results and write access but you can mostly say arrays are pointers.